# Microcontroller resets multiple times and eventually blows up in a boost converter application

Tags: microcontroller, dc-dc-converter, boost

I'm working on a high voltage (100V input, ~600V output) boost converter, and have decided to use an 8-bit Nuvoton MS51PC0AE microcontroller to control the output voltage (instead of using a PWM controller IC or an IC dedicated for the purpose). I chose to use a micro since there was a requirement to provide a user interface as well (LCD, push buttons, etc.).

The microcontroller and the boost converter circuit have a common ground, and I did not want to use isolation amplifiers since there's a cost constraint. The input and output voltages of the converter are fed to the micro's ADC through appropriately scaled voltage dividers, and the micro provides a PWM signal to the switching component (IGBT) through a driver IC. The problem is, that as soon as the micro starts boosting the voltage, the micro resets (this was observed multiple times as was evident from the LCD screen which flashed the initial message multiple times), eventually it blew up and there was shorting between the VCC and GND pins of the micro.

I replaced the micro but observed the same effect multiple times. I'm also running out of micros now.

It would be greatly helpful if someone could tell me where things are going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Schematic:

[image: schematic page 1]
Page 1 of 3

[image: schematic page 2]
Page 2 of 3

[image: schematic page 3]
Page 3 of 3

(Original [schematic PDF on Google Drive is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ssY6r2jvx62N7y8Xul9PRoRTyGeod0aa/view?usp=drivesdk).)

Comment: Show your circuit diagram.

Comment: And your PCB layout, and your code. Manually controlling the switching of a boost converter using a microcontroller that's also doing other things is not trivial and very easy to break things.

Comment: While the question says ``isolation amplifiers`` are not used due to cost constraints, what are the **safety** implications of having the microcontroller with the user interface sharing a common ground with the high voltage side?

Comment: Hi @ChesterGillon, you're correct. The sharing of common ground with the user interface does compromise safety, but the customer was okay with it since he said it would be required only once to save the boost converter's configuration and be removed thereafter (and would not be a part of the final product).

Comment: This is one of many good reasons to avoid doing a highly demanding software project (hard real-time control) and to work with simple controllers like TL494 or UC3843 first. Only once the control scheme is deeply understood, and only once a software platform is deeply understood, well enough that you can guarantee execution under the operating conditions: only then it is justified to pursue a highly integrated from-scratch project like this.

Comment: What's the voltage rating for R13, R14, R17 and R17? What is the IGBT used and, please provide the details of the inductor?

Comment: These are standard 0.25 W resistors. I'm not sure about their voltage ratings since I bought them from a local store. The IGBT being used is 40g120hd and I'm using a 1.5 mH inductor.

Comment: Missing series-protection resistor from LM358 *current-sense output* to protect microcontroller's ADC. This signal can potentially rise to about +14V. GND connections between all these DC supplies and relay are critical (+15V supply, current-sense return, switcher gnd, IGBT gate-drive gnd).

Comment: Where does the +15V come from?

Comment: Is the Boost Converter based upon a reference design, and was the control loop response simulated before trying to control the actual Boost Converter?

Comment: @AmritPalSingh "local store" unmarked 0.25 watt resistors sound highly suspicious to me wrt voltage rating.

Comment: Is the board laid out according to 600V design rules?

Comment: @JohnDoty, I did add creepage barriers at place where high voltage and low voltage traces tend to run near to each other and tried to keep the high voltage track away from the signal lines. I'm just beginning to lay out boards myself and not very familiar with the design rules yet.

Comment: @glen_geek Thanks for your response. Wouldn't the 1n4148 diodes clip any voltage greater than+5v? If not, and I need to add a series resistor to the current sense signal, how big the resistor should be?

Comment: Amrit, need my eyes checked. My error - 1N4148 will clamp to about +5.7V, straining against LM358's internal current limiting. +5.7V is still too high...I'd add a series resistor of at least a few kilohms between those diodes and microcontroller input. Perhaps even a capacitor to GND as you've done for other ADC inputs.

Comment: unused LM358 inputs should be grounded

Comment: yes the diode will clamp the output to approximately 5.6V but that breaks the feedback loop...  I hope the current sense feature is not important.

Comment: The output if the LM358 will easily pump the 5V rail up close to 15V. The 7805 regulator will not pull the rail down if something else (the LM358) is pulling it up.

Comment: It's been a while me messing around with this issue. After trying "everything" which seemed to be causing trouble, I decided to use a different microcontroller (STM32). To my surprise, the MCU no longer resets and hasn't blown up yet with me testing the circuit with high and low voltages. But I cannot wrap my head around this, how could the same circuit cause issues with the other MCU? Perhaps a faulty batch?